# Make MPlayer show all playback state change message in output

Tags: mplayer

I'm currently using MPlayer in slave mode for a video player im making.
As of currently, the media player shows `====  PAUSED  ====` when it's paused and I can read the output for this status to know when the video is paused.
The command line arg i am using as of now is `msglevel identify=6:statusline=-1` (i disabled statusline as it produced `A:   0.7 V:   0.6 A-V:  0.068 ...` and unneccessary stuff)
What do I need to set the msglevel (or anything else) so that it will also show `====  PLAYING  ====` or any indication that it started playing, stopped, media ended, loading, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out how to get if the video is paused.

By sending command `pausing_keep_force get_property pause` to mplayer, it responds with `ANS_pause=no` if not paused, and `ANS_pause=yes` if paused. Problem solved.

Comment: Hi there, I have the same problem. How are you getting this value as variable?  When I run your command, ANS_pause appears in console, where mplayer was started.

Comment: @peter, you have to dump all of the mplayer output to a file or fifo and search it. `mplayer myfile.mp3 > /tmp/mplayerDump`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I can decipher from the OP's answer to his/her own question, he/she was looking for a way to determine whether mplayer was paused or playing. I've written a little bash script that can handle this task with some simple function calls.

You can actually inspect the last couple lines of mplayer's output to see if mplayer is paused. I put together a little bash library that can be used to query some status information about mplayer. Take a look on [my GitHub](https://github.com/nbros652/mplayer-status/). There are instructions for integrating my script with other bash scripts.

If you implement my script, you will need to play your media file using the `playMediaFile` function. Then you can simply call the `isPaused` function as a condition in bash like this:

```
if isPaused; then
    # do something
fi

# or
if ! isPaused; then
    # do something
fi

# or
ifPaused && #do something
```